# How to use CreateTextServices, ITextHost correctly in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, richtextbox

I want to implement a windowless rich text box, but I only found some C++ examples, I want to implement it in C#, but calling the **CreateTextServices** function always has an error("**FatalExecutionEngineError**")。

Compile the platform for any CPU, **Win10 (x64) runs correctly, Win7 (x86) runs incorrectly**. After compiling on Win7, Win10 can also run correctly.

```
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    try
    {
        IntPtr pUnk = IntPtr.Zero;
        if (WinAPI.CreateTextServices(IntPtr.Zero, this, out pUnk) < 0)
            throw new Win32Exception();

        //Guid iid = typeof(WinInterface.ITextServices).GUID;
        //Marshal.QueryInterface(pUnk, ref iid, out ppv);
        //services = (WinInterface.ITextServices)
        //    Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(ppv, typeof(WinInterface.ITextServices));

    }
    finally
    {
        //Marshal.Release(pUnk);
    }
}
[DllImport(ExternDll.Msftedit, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int CreateTextServices(
            IntPtr punkOuter,
            WinInterface.ITextHost pITextHost,
            out IntPtr ppUnk
            );
```

I am using VS2017 and VS2013, why this error occurs, I can't find any clues at the moment.

Comment: I have a feeling that this library was compiled with `__fastcall` by mistake and has remained so ever since for back compat reasons. That would be consistent with the symptoms of code working in 64 bit (single calling convention only) but not 32 bit.

Comment: @David Heffernan But compiled with Win32 project, it can run on both 64-bit and 32-bit.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what bitness all the components are. If you did some research I think you'd find that I am right about fastcall.

Comment: @David Heffernan My C++ is poor X(

Comment: When one is missing some knowledge, one spends time and invests in learning

Comment: @David Heffernan Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: I've the same issue and after some research, I think the problem doesn't come from `CreateTextServices` wich uses `stdcall` as expected, but it comes from the `ITextHost` implementation in .NET. If you look at `textserv.h`, `ITextHost` interface methods don't define the calling convention (this is very unusual for COM objects, it should be `stdcall`), so it's in fact `thiscall`. So the crash happens when calling `CreateTextServices` because its implementation calls back into the first host function it uses, which happens to be `ITextHost::TxGetPropertyBits`

Comment: @SimonMourier Although I don't know how you solved it, but I have re-created it here, it is still like this.

Comment: @SimonMourier
Thank you very much. I'm very glad to have found the answer after many hours of frustration.